# How can I find the form that called the current method?

Tags: c#, vb.net

When logging in vb.net, how can I learn the name of the form that called the current method? 
I know all about

> System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().

so I used this

vb.net

```
Dim form_Name as String=(New System.Diagnostics.StackTrace).GetFrame(1).GetMethod.GetParameters(1).Member.DeclaringType.FullName
```

c#

```
  string form_Name = (new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace()).GetFrame(1).GetMethod.GetParameters(1).Member.DeclaringType.FullName;
```

But I faced a problem using `Form_Name` as `Form`

I am hoping to find a way, I want to get the Form object name  to use it as Form not string

Comment: `But I faced a problem ... ` and that problem you faced is ...?

Comment: i couldn't use the variable as Form Type  ...is it not clear ??

Comment: No, that doesn't make any sense. You are trying to use a string as a type? Why? You are writing a logger. You don't need to call methods on the form, you just need to print its name.

Comment: okay  i want to get the form object name  to use it as Form not string

Comment: inside the form, add a hidden field to carry the form id or something, on submit you can check at server side

Comment: @ARUN - I think the above question is about a Winforms application not ASP.NET web forms

Comment: `i couldn't use the variable as Form Type ...is it not clear ??`. Not it was not clear what you are asking since in your question you asked how to find the name of a Form. And you answered this question onyourself. Now in your comment you are asking for a complete different thing. You can instantiate a Form with the previous found name. But that is not the *object* which called your current method.

Comment: e.g. with the [Activator.CreateInstance methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VB: `Dim callingForm = Application.OpenForms.Item(form_Name)`